# android how to install apk silently?

Tags: android, permissions, installation

I'm trying to make an app that installs apk silently.
But when I try, it always gives errors.
I dont really get what I should do now.
I think I've already tried all the ways posted on the web. Can anyone help me know anything else I should try now?

```
package com.example.filetest;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.ViewDebug.FlagToString;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    int count = 0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        /* File file = new File("/storage/external_storage/sda1","Scratch-v0.953.apk"); 
         Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);     intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file),
     "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
     intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
     startActivity(intent);
    */
    File file = new File("/storage/external_storage/sda1/FingerPCSettings");
    //File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
    Log.i("TAG","exists = "+file.exists());
    File[] temp = file.listFiles();
    if(temp==null){
        Log.e("TAG","temp is null");
        return;
    }
        InstallAPK(temp[0]);




}

public static void InstallAPK(File file){
    Log.i("TAG", "install called "+file);

    if(file.exists()){
        try {   
            String command;
            command = "/system/bin/pm install -r " + file.getAbsolutePath();
            Log.i("TAG", "command="+command);
            command = command.substring(0, 1);
            Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { command });
            proc.waitFor();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }
  }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.i("TAG", "###########RESUME CALLEd");
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

When I try this code, I get errors as follows.

```
05-20 17:34:18.898: W/System.err(6272): java.io.IOException: Error running exec(). Command: [/] Working Directory: null Environment: null
05-20 17:34:18.898: W/System.err(6272):     at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(ProcessManager.java:211)
05-20 17:34:18.898: W/System.err(6272):     at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:173)
05-20 17:34:18.898: W/System.err(6272):     at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:128)
05-20 17:34:18.898: W/System.err(6272):     at com.example.filetest.MainActivity.InstallAPK(MainActivity.java:59)
05-20 17:34:18.898: W/System.err(6272):     at com.example.filetest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:43)
05-20 17:34:18.898: W/System.err(6272):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5273)
05-20 17:34:18.898: W/System.err(6272):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1101)
05-20 17:34:18.898: W/System.err(6272):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
05-20 17:34:18.898: W/System.err(6272):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
05-20 17:34:18.898: W/System.err(6272):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
05-20 17:34:18.898: W/System.err(6272):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
05-20 17:34:18.898: W/System.err(6272):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-20 17:34:18.898: W/System.err(6272):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-20 17:34:18.898: W/System.err(6272):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
05-20 17:34:18.908: W/System.err(6272):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-20 17:34:18.908: W/System.err(6272):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-20 17:34:18.908: W/System.err(6272):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:788)
05-20 17:34:18.908: W/System.err(6272):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:604)
05-20 17:34:18.908: W/System.err(6272):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-20 17:34:18.908: W/System.err(6272): Caused by: java.io.IOException: Permission denied
05-20 17:34:18.908: W/System.err(6272):     at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(Native Method)
05-20 17:34:18.908: W/System.err(6272):     at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(ProcessManager.java:209)
05-20 17:34:18.908: W/System.err(6272):     ... 18 more
```

Here's my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.filetest"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0"
android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"
coreApp = "true"
   >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="19"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DELETE_PACKAGES"/>


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 

    >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

I can't get what I should do right now.. Does Anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: i need your help. Can u give me some time. I will be very grateful to u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to run your command:

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { command });
```

Instead of this use the code:

```
 Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cd " + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/.command");
```

And also verify your command constructed string should be correct.print the substring in your log.

Comment: Thanks but.. umm.. I dont get it.. what's this code for?

Comment: use API to run your command using exec by this want may be it helps.

Comment: stil not working.. is it right to put my command variable to your .command part?

Comment: this is the one way to run your Command(whatever you trying to execute at adb shell terminal) so assaign/save your expected Command in command variable

Answer (score 0):

This exception is thrown because you are trying to create the file in the root directory.

Remove the `/` at the beginning when creating the new file so your path becomes a relative path:

```
File file = new File("storage/external_storage/sda1/FingerPCSettings");
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm already using "substring" to take 1st slash off, so I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: I just tried yours and unfortunately it's not working